# How to obtain which values in one column are associated with certain values in another column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
##      ID        DOB sector meters Oct   Res_FROM     Res_TO   Exp_FROM
## 1 20100 1979-08-24    H38   6400   W 1979-08-15 1991-05-15 1979-08-24
## 2 20101 1980-05-05    B01   1600  NW 1980-05-15 1991-04-15 1980-05-15
## 3 20102 1979-03-17    H04   1600  SW 1972-06-15 1979-08-15 1979-03-17
## 4 20103 1981-11-30    B09   3200  NE 1982-01-15 1984-01-15 1982-01-15
## 5 20103 1981-11-30    B37   8000   N 1984-01-15 1986-04-15 1984-01-15
## 6 20104 1978-09-01    B09   3200  NE 1982-01-15 1984-01-15 1982-01-15
```

In reality, there are about 14,000 rows, but only 8 directions as shown in the "Oct" column (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). I wanted to create a list with each of the 8 directions shown and which sectors fall into those directions. There are 100 sectors, some are just not shown here since I condensed the data. How would I go about getting this output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```r
Octs <- unique(dat$Oct)
lapply(setNames(Octs, Octs), \(x) unique(dat$sector[dat$Oct == x]))
#> $W
#> [1] "H38"
#> 
#> $NW
#> [1] "B01"
#> 
#> $SW
#> [1] "H04"
#> 
#> $NE
#> [1] "B09"
#> 
#> $N
#> [1] "B37"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>